# Implement function sum(a)(b)(c) using callbacks in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, callback

I' was asked in an interview to create a function having signature like sum(a)(b)(c) using callback, the way i solved it was this:

```
function sum(a){
   return function(b){
      return function(c){
         return a+b+c;  
      }
   }
}
```

but the interviewer was looking for callback approach, which i'm unable to implement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called **currying**. Try researching that, and if you have trouble understanding or implementing it, we can help you here.

Comment: @MátéSafranka Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the question showing an example of currying?

Comment: It is, sort of. Currying is a more general approach that allows functions to be composed to any arity; OP's example works, but there's little practical use to it. Hackernoon has a pretty good article on how the general principle works: https://hackernoon.com/currying-in-js-d9ddc64f162e

Comment: this dose the same thing: `var sum = a => b => c => a + b + c`... but i must agree with others that this question is to broad. it's unclear of how he wanted it to work. If i got that kind of question i would say, *"No! that's just dumb. Why would you ever do that? there are better more understandable way do write better code"*

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function as callback for the wanted operation like `sum`, which takes two operands and an array for the values and a function which returns itself.

For getting a final value, you need to implement a `toString` method, which returns a final value.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function partial(fn) {
    function f(v) {
         stack.push(v);
         if (stack.length === fn.length) {
             stack = [fn(...stack)];
         }
         return f;
    }
    f.toString = function () { return stack[0]; };
    
    var stack = [];
    return f;
}

console.log(partial(sum)(3)(4)(5));
```